# Left side menu with Tab bar?

Tags: ios, menu, uitabbarcontroller

I would like to implement a left side menu with a Tab bar controller in the same App. I already use Tab bar controller, but I would like to implement in only one UITableViewController a left side menu. Is it possible ?
I've tried MFSideMenu but it's too difficult to use... have you got any idea ?

iOS 7, Xcode 5.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it is possible [Check this like](http://swiftdeveloperblog.com/mobile-app-with-uitabbarcontroller-sliding-side-menus/) for the tutorial. By using [MMDrawerController](https://github.com/mutualmobile/MMDrawerController) you can achieve in swift.

And I Done the task check this [git link](https://github.com/ERaBala/LeftMenu-inTabBar/tree/Add-Menu) after clone `pod install`